# Apache doesn't allow access to media files

Tags: django, apache, static, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set up my Apache so it can serve media files saved inside a Django Backend.
Django is already in production mode (`DEBUG=False`) and I have SSL set up.
I have one domain with a reverse proxy serving my frontend and a subdomain (api.domain) serving my Django backend. I'm now trying to serve my media files in `backend/app/media/` from apache.
My subdomain ssl .conf file in `sites-available` contains the following code inside the `<VirtualHost *:433>`:

```
Alias /media/ /home/backend/main/media/
<Directory /home/backend/main/media>
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I tried this code block also inside my `apache2.conf` file but that didn't work either. Also worth mentioning, I don't get the default Apache "Service Unavailable" error when trying to access the files via the browser. I get (only if the Django Server runs) the Django production "Not Found" view.
Therefore I guess it handles my request via Django which is expectable since I'm accessing the api subdomain serving Django. How can I manage to access my files served by Apache? When trying to access my domain, I get forwarded to my frontend and when trying it via the subdomain, I get forwarded to Django.

I'm kind of lost and every help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I fixed it by setting up a separate `cdn` subdomain and pasting the code from my question inside it's .conf file. Now I can serve my files via this subdomain and everything works